# Building with CMake gives segfault on strlen

Tags: c, cmake

I am creating a game in SDL2 and while everything mostly works, whenever I build with CMake, I can't open any (image) file with a string, because I get a segmentation fault. I happen to also have a `Makefile` available which doesn't give the same result (It works fine).

The function I'm calling as declared:

```
extern SDL_Texture* RenderSomething(int x, int y, float space, char** path, SDL_Renderer* Renderer);
```

(I've changed it to a double pointer to see if it was a problem).

The code I'm calling it as:

```
  RenderSomething(mouseX, mouseY, size, &__path__, Renderer);
```

Options I use in the Makefile:

```
-Wno-switch-default -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wredundant-decls -Wsign-conversion -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wundef -Wno-unused -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wall -Wextra -O5
```

Declaration of `__path__`:

```
char* __path__ = "/the/path/to/my/image.png";
```

The segmentation fault as described by gdb:

```
Thread 1 "app.bin" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a474bd in __strlen_avx2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

The implementation of `RenderSomething`:

```
SDL_Texture* RenderSomething(int x, int y, float space, char** path, SDL_Renderer* Renderer) {
    SDL_Rect rect;
    SDL_Surface* srf = IMG_Load(*path);
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    if (!srf) {
        /* insert error handling code here */
    }
    else {
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer, srf);
        SDL_FreeSurface(srf);
        if (!texture) {
            /* insert even more error handling here */
        } else {
            SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
            rect.h = 32 * space / 2; // Every image is 32x32, so we don't bother with querying the dimensions of it.
            rect.w = 32 * space / 2;
            rect.x = x;
            rect.y = y;
            SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
        }
    }
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: How is `Render()` related to `RenderSomething()`? What is its declaration?

Comment: That's a typo sorry, I meant to write `RenderSomething` there as well.

Comment: So if you can change `RenderSomething()` argument `char** path` to a double-star pointer, that must be your own function, and you should post it.

Comment: Are all necessary sources specified in the Cmake script? It looks very much like the file with `char* __path__ = "/the/path/to/my/image.png";` is not included in the build with Cmake.

Comment: I'm going to post it, but i hope it's clear that my problem is not with the code, but the way it compiles, and it might be some CMake flag causing this.

Comment: @u-235 It's the entry point file, so by 99.999% it is specified.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that the problem isn't in the code. I've had a few cases where an array overrun screwed up a random variable that happened to be nearby. And it depended on compiler options.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and examine the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was caused by a nearby #ifdef statement.. Which i had enabled in CMake. I don't know how did it happen but it did.
Thanks to @u-235 for the advice, since the code was actually screwed up by nearby symbols :)